# what are the benefits of clojure promises over using add-watch?

Tags: clojure

I am looking at different ways of implementing concurrency in clojure and these seem to be two competing ways of doing the same thing, so I was wondering where I should use each technique.

Comment: Do you mean a code example of what a promoise and add-watch is , or a code example of how they do the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Watches and promises are both very useful for concurrency, but are suited to slightly different uses. You may well find that you want to use both in different places in the same application.

Use a watch if you want **notification of change in a reference**. For example, if one thread is handling events and updates a ref in response to some of these events, you could use add-watch to enable other parts of your system to receive notification of the update. A single watch can handle many updates over time.

Use a promise if you want to **pass another thread a handle to access a value that is not yet computed**. If the other thread tries to dereference the promise, they will block until the computation of the promise has finished (i.e. the original thread places a value in the promise via "deliver"). A single promise is only intended to be used once - after that it is just a fixed value.

Answer (score 11):

[Watches](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/add-watch) are about one entity in a concurrent system and [promises](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/promise) are about two entities.

promises are more of a way to communicate between events on different timelines. They provide a way for a piece of code to receive a response with out having to worry about what mechanism will be providing the answer. the original code path can create a promise and pass it to two different code paths in a single thread, or threads, or agents, or nodes in a distributed system. then when one of the threads/agents/refs needs an answer it can block on the promise with out having to know anything about the entity that will be fulfilling the promise. And when the other thread/agent/ref/other figures out the answer it can fulfill the promise with out having to know anything about the entity that is waiting on the promise (or not yet waiting).

promises are a communication mechanism across timelines that are **independent of the concurrently mechanism used.**

Watches are a way of specifying a function to call when an atom or ref changes. this is a way of communicating intent to all the **future states of a single agent/ref**, by saying "Hey, make sure this condition is always true", or "log the change here".